# How to add category selector on admin product form in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, category-tree

[image]

I added a select category in product form but it doesn't work.After selecting categories and saving the selections are not stored. Please help me with this problem. Maybe i'm missing something someone please give me a more complete description .Thank .

```
file product_form.xml

.............................
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
  
    <fieldset name="product-details">
        <field name="main_categories">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Main Category</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.main_categories</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

```
Setup InstallData.php

....................
   public function install(
      ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
      ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
      /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
      $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
      $setup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);         
       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
              \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
              'main_categories',
              [
                  'group' => 'General',
                  'type' => 'varchar',
                  'label' => 'Main Category',
                  'input' => 'text',
                  'source' => '',
                  'frontend' => '',
                  'backend' => '',
                  'required' => false,
                  'sort_order' => 11,
                  'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                  'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                  'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                  'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                  'visible' => true,
                  'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                  'visible_on_front' => true
              ]
          );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add tree input renderer you can add this code in your ui component form xml

````
<field name="parent">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parent Category</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.parent</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>```
````

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't do the save

Comment: your answer i read it in a few places but it didn't work so i asked this question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best solution, but in my case that worked.

1. make sure your product attribute exists and has been installed correctly (i.e. check the database after install).
2. change the datascope in your ui form:
   from: `<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.main_categories</item>`
   to:
   `<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">main_categories</item>`
3. Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` again to make sure the config is really gotten and caches are clean

Unfortunately this will result in a syncing of both custom eav attribute and the field defined in your ui_component form file. So if you changed the ui component, this should also change the value of the input field of your custom eav attribute (in your case the attribute with code `main_categories` ).

But besides that, it should save now.

To hide the custom eav attribute (so in order to not have 2 different fields), I personally added a AttributeFieldModifier, and added a css class to the field. Create two files for that:

1. File: `Namespace/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml` with content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool"
                 type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_HERE" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\ModuleName\Modifier\AttributeFieldModifier</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

2. File: `Namespace/ModuleName/Modifier/AttributeFieldModifier.php` with content

```php
<?php

namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;

/**
 * Class AttributeFieldModifier
 *
 * Extend the attribute meta information for the main_category product eav attribute
 */
class AttributeFieldModifier extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
     * Modify meta information in order to HIDE the actual eav attribute with name "YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_HERE".
     * 
     * The eav attribute itself is needed as a workaround for saving data of the product-details form ui_component.
     * This ui component only provides a category select field, just like the regular ('category_ids') form field in
     * the administration, showing a list of categories as a tree. It does not save the data. Therefore we 
     * automatically apply changes made in the ui comonent and write the resulting data (i.e. "5", meaning: 
     * category with id 5) into the eav attribute field.
     * 
     * In order to not have 2 fields, we hide the eav attribute field via css class "hidden".
     *
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $name = 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_HERE';
        $meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                'product-details' => [
                    'children' => [
                        'container_' . $name => [
                            'children' => [
                                $name => [
                                    'arguments' => [
                                        'data' => [
                                            'config' => [
                                                'additionalClasses' => 'hidden',
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * Modify data
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

** MAKE SURE** not to forget changing the placeholders in my code examples (`Namespace`, `ModuleName` & `YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_HERE`).

For **reference** (but yours should be fine as well) this is my ui_component form:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="product-details">
        <field name="main_category">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Main Category</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">product-details</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">main_category</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Again - I really doubt this is the preferred way of doing that. But at least its a solution.

If it does the job, please upvote :)